# Node module depth problems with npm2 in OSX?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

When using node.js with Windows-based projects, it's recommended that you use an npm package such as `flatten-packages` to prevent directory depth from getting out of control. This is because Windows has a MAX_PATH limitation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/69

Are there potential problems of node_modules folder nesting growing out of control in OSX? This question is more about contrasting development between Windows and OSX in Node.js

Answer (score 1):

NPM v3 uses a much flatter directory structure: https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3

> While npm2 installs all dependencies in a nested way, npm3 tries to mitigate the deep trees and redundancy that such nesting causes. npm3 attempts this by installing some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way, in the same directory as the primary dependency that requires it.

That's probably the simplest solution to your problem.

The actual maximum path length on OSX [seems to be 1016 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140575/mac-os-x-lion-what-is-the-max-path-length), so about 4 times longer than on Windows.

Comment: My question is more about the limitations of npm2 in relation to OSX. I did know about this, though. I'm not running into this problem, at the moment. It's more of a hypothetical.